# Creating dynamic tabs using ng2-bootstrap tabs

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I am trying to use ng2-bootstrap tabs component for generating dynamic tabs.

I want Component as the content generator for tabs.

Have anyone tried developing this use case?.All the samples in ng2-bootstrap points to static content

I have hard time linking Component to a Tab Directive

Comment: Please provide some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly this snippet will basically do what you were asking for:

```
let pages = [
  {
  "title" = "Page 1",
  "data" = {
    whatever data you have ...
  },
  {
  "title" = "Page 2",
  "data" = {
    whatever data you have ...
  },
  {
  "title" = "Page 3",
  "data" = {
    whatever data you have ...
  }
]
```

and then you can create your content

```
<tabset *ngIf="pages.length > 0">
  <tab *ngFor="let page of pages" heading="{{ page.title }}" class='tab'>
    DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO WITH YOUR

    page.data

    IN HERE
  </tab>
</tabset>
```